# How to associate descendant models to a parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
Account
  has_many :libraries

Library
  has_many :topics
  belongs_to :account

Topic
  has_many :functions
  belongs_to :library

Function
  has_one :example
  belongs_to :topic

Example
  belongs_to :function
```

I would like to be able to able to do things such as:

```
some_account.libraries
some_account.topics
some_account.functions
some_account.examples
```

In addition, I would like to be able to assign an account to a descendant, i.e

```
some_example.account = some_account
some_function.account = some_account
some_topic.account = some_account
some_library.account = some_account
```

To give some context:
I am letting a user (Account) create each Library, Topic, Function, Example. record separately. Then a user is free to change how the records are associated: Change the topic of a Function, move a Topic to a different Library, add an example to a function, and so on.

To my understanding no matter what record is created, I would need to assign it to a user (account) so that I can have a list of each Model records that a user has created, as well as prevent other users from seeing stuff that doesn't belong to them

Although I might be overcomplicating, I really don't know :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put

```
belongs_to :account
```

on each entity a user can make... and add a foreign key, and

```
Account
  has_many :libraries
  has_many :topics
  has_many :functions
  has_many :examples
```

(Note: I use the hobo_fields gem to make migrations easier)

That way.. if they change which functions are in which topics etc.. you can't loose who created it.

If you want to make sure users cannot add their topics to someone else's library just put validation on the record to prevent it.

Comment: Ah I forgot to add them in the post. Yes, I do have them, I had tried has_many :topics, :through => :library, but how further down the chain can I go, so that I can reach the Example model from the Account? Is it possible to have multiple has_many's. how would it look like?

Comment: Yep you can just keep going.. and once you have an association you can then do a has_many :through .. against that to set up the next association.. [I'll extend my answer]

Comment: Hm, I can do account.topics, but deeper than that I am getting an error. ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: topics.account_id:. I will rebuild my db from scratch and see.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but do I additionally need to add account_id foreign key (belongs_to :account) in both Function and Example models? Or should that just work having the has_many :through chain specified in Account?

Comment: You're right.. I'm mis-leading you.. I should read the whole question before I answer :(